# Dettman's Applied Complex Variables Theorem 4.2.5 Correction (Normal Families)

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

I need someone to decide whether I'm going crazy.  Dettman states the following theorem without proof:

[Theorem 4.2.5](https://books.google.com/books?id=FsnCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=dettman%20theorem%204.2.5&source=bl&ots=O0x9ufpulb&sig=tf8b5SSOItVzx9DjRJJu2uvOmys&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAWoVChMI3MPsm8e8xwIVVFmICh1pQgk0#v=onepage&q=dettman%20theorem%204.2.5&f=false) 
Let $F$ be a family of functions analytic in a domain $D$, where it is uniformly bounded.  Then every sequence of functions in $F$ contains a subsequence which converges to a function in the family.

Now, as stated, I think the theorem is incorrect.  As a counter-example, take $F = (z^n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ on the open unit disk.  As a sequence, these functions converge to 0, which isn't in the family.

So here's my question: Is this theorem unsalvageable, or can it be perturbed to a true statement about normal families?  The theorem of course becomes true if we omit 'in the family,' or if we replace it with 'which is also analytic and bounded in $D$.'  But is there a similar (true!) theorem which guarantees membership in the family?

Comment: Sure, just consider a family that is closed (in the topology of locally uniform convergence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as stated, the theorem is incorrect.

There are two ways to change it to obtain a true theorem, one can weaken the conclusion - here, one drops the erroneous assertion that the limit necessarily belongs to the family - or one can strengthen the premises. Since the space of holomorphic functions is metrisable (in particular, it is a sequential space) in the topology of locally uniform convergence, the limits of all convergent sequences in a subset belong to the subset itself if and only if it is closed, so we can strengthen the premises to require a *closed* (in the topology of locally uniform convergence) family $F$.